# How to access virtual DOM methods from react library?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, virtual-dom

I want to develop an extension which stores DOM changes for every second. I am planning to use react virtual DOM for converting DOM into JS object and comparing two DOM states. I cant find any API for doing so. is there any way I can access react virtual DOM implementation and use it in my project?